# Python: Get string hex XOR two digit checksum

Tags: python, python-2.7, checksum, xor

Newbie here.

I'm trying to get a hex XOR checksum of a string; and I have the following Python 2.7 code:

```
def getCheckSum(sentence):
    calc_cksum = 0
    for s in sentence:
        calc_cksum ^= ord(s)
    return str(hex(calc_cksum)).strip('0x')

print getCheckSum('SOME,1.948.090,SENTENCE,H,ERE')
```

Now this works fine as a dime EXCEPT for when the result contains `0`. If the final value is `02` or `20`, it will print only `2`. I thought about implementing a `.zfill(2)`, but that would only be applicable for cases where `0` precedes the digit; therefore not reliable.

Any solution to why this might be and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the best solution, but works -

```
def getCheckSum(sentence):
    calc_cksum = 0
    for s in sentence:
        calc_cksum ^= ord(s)
    return str(hex(calc_cksum)).lstrip("0").lstrip("x")
```

The issue is that you are removing both "0" and "x"  either as leading or trailing. I changed that to sequential `lstrip`.

You can use regex `re` as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.format` like so:

```
>>> '{:02x}'.format(2)
'02'
>>> '{:02x}'.format(123)
'7b'
```

This will format the integer given into hexadecimal while formatting it to display two digits.

For your code, you'd just do `return '{:02x}'.format(calc_cksum)`